# Raspberry Pi 3.5 Inch Display Works on Pi 2 B but not 3 B+

Tags: pi-2, display, pi-3b+

The exact screen is this one. http://www.neosecsolutions.com//products.php?28 On a Raspberry Pi 2 B it boots to raspbian. On the 3 B+ it gives a white screen, The Raspberry Pi 2 B has a white screen on startup. Is there anything else you need to know to help solve the problem?

Comment: screens do not "boot"   ....  a screen is only a display device (some may also contain a touch device)..... does the Pi3B+ boot? .... can you reach it by SSH?

Comment: @jsotola When talking about booting, I meant the Pi, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so the pi doesn't boot at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX It does boot. it just doesn't show anything but white on the display.

Comment: Does the screen come with a ready to boot SDCard? Is that img too old for a 3B+?

Comment: @Dougie It does come with an image file, I put that on the sd card. Is there anything I can do about that, I don't know how to check if it's too old.

Comment: All you can do is Google your device type and "3B+" in quotes to see if someone has been there before. I can just about guarantee that the firmware on that card is too old. If you can boot it in another RPi run ```sudo rpi-update``` to update it.